# Question Dapper read repository and write repository c#

Tags: c#, dependency-injection, repository

I'm working on a C# project where I need to implement two types of repositories: one for read operations and another for write operations. My goal is to have the write repository inherit all methods from the read repository and then add its own specific write operations.

Depending on the use case, Command or Query (CQRS), I want to use the CompanyRepository for Commands (CRUD) with the connection database write/read. In the case of a Use Case Query (GET), I want to use CompanyReadRepository.

I want to reuse the methods of CompanyReadRepository inside CompanyRepository to reduce duplicate code in our code base.

Does anyone have an idea or suggestion on how to implement this?

Here's an example of what I am trying to implement

```
        public class CompanyRepository : CompanyReadRepository, ICompanyRepository 

        public CompanyRepository(IOptions<RepositoryOptions> options) 
            : base(options.Value.SqlConnectionString)  
        {

        }

        public class CompanyReadRepository : RepositoryBase, ICompanyReadRepository

        public CompanyReadRepository(IOptions<RepositoryOptions> options)
            : base(options.Value.ReadOnlySqlConnectionString)
        {
            connectionString = options.Value.SqlConnectionString;
            _options = options.Value;
        }
```

Comment: Can you rephrase the question? What are you trying to avoid. Inheritance should work.

Comment: Using inheritance seems like a reasonable approach. Read write as a subtype of read only is logical

Comment: The problem i have is how to select one connection string or other depending on the Interface using IOptions<RepositoryOptions> of Dependency inyection

Comment: It's dependency injection container specific but I've never seen one that couldn't do it. Are you using AutoFac, the asp.net-core built-in container?

Comment: I am using the asp.net-core Microsoft.Extensions.DependencyInjection

Comment: There are a lot of ways to do it, but this simplest might be to have different repository options types. Instead of having multiple connection string properties in the same object. There's always the option to use a factory like `services.AddScoped<ICompanyReadRepository>(provider => CompanyReadRepository(pass the right parameters here))`

Comment: Thansk for your comment, but i don't undertand at all this part:
There are a lot of ways to do it, but this simplest might be to have different repository options types. Instead of having multiple connection string properties in the same object

Multiples constructors with differents options types?

Comment: It's hard to be specific when i don't have access to how your di is configured. The simplest thing is to have not have two connection string properties that each respective class knows about. Instead, have an `IReadWriteOptions` interface and an `IReadOptions` interface. They would have different connection string values. The constructs for your repository classes could then be adjusted to take the correct respective options type like `public CompanyReadRepository(IReadOptions options) {}`. The option interfaces would extend one another just like the repository classes do.

Comment: Thanks! I will try this aproach i think will be the easiest an cleanest!